# Get Data from Other Processes using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, wait, pool

(Language is Python 3)

I am writing a program with the module `multiprocessing` and using `Pool`. I need some variable that is shared between all of the processes. The parent process will initialize this variable and pass it as an argument to `p.map()`. I want the child processes to change this variable. The intent of this is because the first part of the child processes' work should be done in parallel (computational work that doesn't need any other processes' data). But, the second part of the processes' work needs to be done in order, one process after another, because they are writing to a file and the contents of that file should be in order. I want each process to wait until the others are done before moving on. I will record the "progress" of the entire program with the variable, e.g. when the first process is done writing to the file, it will increment the variable by one. I want this to be a signal to the next process in line to begin writing to the file. But I need some sort of `waituntil()` function to make the processes wait until the `Value` variable indicates that it is their "turn" to write to the file.

Here are my two problems:

1. I need a variable that the child processes can edit, and the child processes can actually get the value of that variable. What type of variable should I use? Should I use `Value`, `Manager`, or something else?
2. I need the processes to wait until the variable described above equals to a certain value, signaling that it is their turn to write to the file. Is there any sort of `waituntil()` function that I can use?

Comment: I can link my code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Synchronization**.
There are multitudes of different synchronization primitives to choose from.

**You should never attempt to write synchronization primitives on your own, as it is non-trivial to do correctly!**

In your case either an [**Event**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) or a [**Condition**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition) might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks! I think this solves my problem. However, could you please explain what advantages Synchronization has over the other two options? And also why I shouldn't write synchronization on my own?

Comment: @AnishShanbhag When doing parallel programming, you always have to consider concurrent access. There might also be some unexpected behaviour, e.g changes not propagating immidiately due to chaching etc. This is the [Peterson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) which makes sure that only one process / thread at a time can enter a critical section. As you can see, one has to be extra careful when dealing with concurrent access. On top of that, most operating systems offer native implementations which are usually faster. Always use the existing implementations!